# Autowiring issues with a class in Spring data Mongo repository

Tags: spring-data, spring-boot

For a variety of reasons, I ended up using spring boot 1.2.0 RC2. 
So a spring data mongo application that worked fine in spring boot1.1.8 is now having issues.  No code was changed except for the bump to spring boot 1.2.0 RC2.  This is due to the snapshot version of spring cloud moving to this spring boot version.

The repository class is as follows

```
@Repository
public interface OAuth2AccessTokenRepository extends MongoRepository<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken, String> {

    public OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken findByTokenId(String tokenId);

    public OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken findByRefreshToken(String refreshToken);

    public OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken findByAuthenticationId(String authenticationId);

    public List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> findByClientIdAndUserName(String clientId, String userName);

    public List<OAuth2AuthenticationAccessToken> findByClientId(String clientId);
}
```

This worked quite well before the bump in versions and now I see this in the log.

```
19:04:35.510 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: file [/Users/larrymitchell/rpilprojects/corerpilservicescomponents/channelMap/target/classes/com/cisco/services/rpil/mongo/repository/oauth2/OAuth2AccessTokenRepository.class]
```

I do have another mongo repository that is recognized but it was defined as a class implementation

```
@Component 
public class ChannelMapRepository { ... }
```

This one is recognized (I defined it as a implementation class as a workaround for another problem I had).  This class is recognized and seems to work fine.

```
19:04:35.513 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/larrymitchell/rpilprojects/corerpilservicescomponents/channelMap/target/classes/com/cisco/services/rpil/services/Microservice.class]
```

Anyone have an idea why?  I looked up the various reasons for why component scanning would not work and nothing lends itself to my issue.

Comment: Works as expected and the messages tell you why. Your interface is an interface and not detected by component scanning and it never will (it didn't did in earlier versions). The interface one is detected by Spring Data MongoDB and behavior is added by that.

Comment: As stated, the only difference in the code is that the version of spring boot changed.  The code worked fine before that change.  Look at his guide and you will see that defining the repository as an interface is the accepted way to do so.  The implementation class is created by spring data: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: Which is what I said... You are using Spring Boot so also make sure you are using Spring Boot to manage your dependencies, use the Spring Boot starters to pull in your dependencies (i.e. `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` in this case) and don't try to fiddle around with your own. Please add your pom to see what (or if) is missing/haywire in there.

Comment: I am using spring cloud 1.0.0 Snapshot which pulls in the spring boot jars through its dependency management.  I have the spring boot starter for mongo in there already.  All of this was working on spring cloud as of last Thursday and it stopped.  I noticed that the new spring cloud starters moved from spring framework 4.0.7 to 4.1.2 and spring boot from 1.1.8 to 1.2.0 RC1.  My pom is fairly long so I will try to put together a small sample in git and paste the link.

Comment: The newer spring boot has a newer Spring Data MongoDB version. So might be that something has changed (some property names also changed in that version!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `@Repository` annotation?  Worked [for me](https://github.com/hoserdude/to-boot/commit/67b277af9e3332ef8a2966ce206442485ac4c2f7).  This was an issue in [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1929) as well.